React router: electron no renderiza la app de preact
tengo una build de preact y electron (estoy utilizando electron forge) carga todos los assets y el html pero renderiza nada en el div app, no aparece ningun error en consola ni en la dev tools, en un navegador normal si renderiza.
La estructura es asi:
    └── vite preact
    └── forge.config.js
    └── package-lock.json
    └── package.json
    └── src
        └── icon.png
        └── index.js
        └── ipc.js
        └── main.json
        └── menu.js
        └── preload.js
        └── renderer
            └── bootstrap-icons-BOrJxbIo.woff
            └── bootstrap-icons-BtvjY1KL.woff2
            └── index-CbBe9Fpq.js
            └── index-CI6m9ooI.css
            └── index.html
            └── loader.js
            └── tabler-icons-B997weg5.woff
            └── tabler-icons-CzBzkdZH.ttf
            └── tabler-icons-Zo3WWo8f.woff2
            └── vite.svg
        └── settings.json
        └── template
            └── index.js
        └── utils.js

y la configuracion de vite es asi

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [preact()],
  base: './',
  build:{
    outDir: '../src/renderer',
  }
  
})

la configuracion de electron es basicamente la de la documentacion

habia un problema de react router al final cambie BrowserRouter por HashRouter
render(
    <HashRouter>
        <AppProvider>
            <App />
        </AppProvider>
    </HashRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('app')!
)

